# Compare 2 excel columns for similarity and return the matched values in datatable using openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

I have to compare 2 columns present in different excel sheets and return the matched values using openxml(C#).Both the columns have some account Numbers.
I am able to get the unmatched values using the below code.But I need the matched values.Please suggest.

```
public static DataTable DocomparisionCOA_ACCT(DataSet dtPrimaryFile, DataSet dtValidationFile)
{
    DataTable COA_BU = new DataTable();
    DataTable validationsheet1 = dtValidationFile.Tables["COA"];
    DataTable primarydatafile = dtPrimaryFile.Tables["JE"];
    var qry1 = validationsheet1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => new { bu = a["Acct"].ToString() });
    var qry2 = primarydatafile.AsEnumerable().Select(b => new { bu = b["ACCT"].ToString() });
    var exceptAB = qry1.Except(qry2);
    COA_BU = (from a in validationsheet1.AsEnumerable()
              join ab in exceptAB on a["ACCT"].ToString() equals ab.bu
              select a).CopyToDataTable();
    DataColumn AcctColumn = COA_BU.Columns["Accts"];
    return COA_BU;
}
```

Comment: You are working with `DataTables` not `OpenXML` in the code you have provided.

Comment: Yes, i can bring the data from excecl sheet in datatables, now i want to compare the columns in both datatables.

Comment: `List<string> columnData1 = primarydatafile .AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[i].ToString()).ToList();` Load the columns into list and compare them